# How do I query to get all the retweets from Twitter streaming API?

Tags: mongodb, twitter

I created a streaming API to capture all the retweets from an account. I save all the results in Mongodb.

Here's the code

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        mydata = json.loads(data)
        db.raw_tweets.insert_one(mydata)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        mydata = json.loads(status)
        db.error_tweets.insert_one(mydata)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
    stream.filter(follow=['121817564'])
```

I believe that I captured almost everything however. There's one tweet with 5000k retweets on Twitter but when I query on my MongoDb I only get 1,300 records. I'm not sure if I miss anything? I'm not hoping to get the exact same number but at least it should be close enough.

Here's the query I use in MongoDB.

```
db.getCollection('raw_tweets').find({'retweeted_status.id_str':'636345902915911680'}).count()
```

Maybe my query is not correct to get all the retweets?

Answer (score 1):

Your mongoDB query looks ok to me.
Now there can be many possible reasons for missing retweets:

- twitter streaming api **does not** guarantee that you will get each and every tweet specified in your filter, you should check limit messages returned by twitter to check if you are missing some tweets.
- The filter you provide in your code is for following a user not a 'track' keywords filter.
- **Most probably** you are missing retweets that were created before you started tracking. (streaming api doesn't deliver tweets created past the time you stated listening).